# Invalid syntax for returning a formatted list in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, time

I made a program in Python 3.7 that doesn't run in Python 2.7.6. The program is meant to break seconds up into seconds, minutes, hours, days and years. The issue is happening with this particular part of the code:

```
return f' {remainder} {metric}' + ('s,' if remainder != 1 else ','), int(val / metric_val)  # returns 'second' or 'seconds' as well as a new 'current_time', rounded down
```

And when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solution import *
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 24
    return f' {remainder} {metric}' + ('s,' if remainder != 1 else ','), int(val / metric_val)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What has to be changed to make this code work for 2.7.6?

Comment: f strings aren't in python 2.x, use other string formatting methods

Answer (score 1):

I see that this Kata is available only in Python version 2.7.6.
"f strings" formatting is not available in this version, thus you get an `invalid syntax` error.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @ArunPratap, it provides an exact answer to the question of the author. I don't understand why it should be a comment, it is not a request for clarification nor a suggestion.

Comment: it will be better if you provide some more details and description so that op can get idea or you can post it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

The moment I copied and pasted the error message, I realised that what must have caused the error message was that the idea of formatting a string with using code like `f'{value}'` mustn't have existed in Python version 2.7.6 and switching to using code like `'{}'.format(value)` was required. I tried this and the code was successful in Python 2.7.6.